# Send Email Via Gmail SwiftMailer Symfony2

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send email with swiftmailer via commande but i got this error message
the commande :

```
php app/console swiftmailer:email:send
```

The error:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com
```

Why is that's ?
My configuration parameters.yml file looks like this :

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
    mailer_user: my gmail
    mailer_password: my password
    secret: secret
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
#app/config/parameters.yml

parameters:
# ...
     mailer_transport: gmail
     mailer_host:      ~
     mailer_user:      your_gmail_username
     mailer_password:  your_gmail_password
```

Comment: the same error
**Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com**

Comment: Do u have a something with the command  `ping smtp.gmail.com` in your console?

Comment: Yes
`Paquets : envoyés = 4, reçus = 4, perdus = 0 (perte 0%),`

Answer (score 0):

Configure your SwiftMailer(config.yml):

```
swiftmailer:
      transport: %mailer_transport%
      encryption: ssl
      host:      %mailer_host%
      username:  %mailer_user%
      password:  %mailer_password%
      spool:     { type: memory }
```

Comment: try using mail for transport not gmail